# DIscord bot. JS Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I can't get this to work. Here is my main file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
  bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
  const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

  for(const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(./commands/${file});
    bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
  }

 if (message.content == 'ping' || message.content == 'Ping') {
   //message.channel.send('Pong');
   bot.commands.get('ping').execute(message);
```

And my file *ping.js*:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'test',
  description: "Tester ting",
  execute(message, args) {
    message.channel.send("STOR TEST")
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
```

I try to get my Bot to anwser me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a little typo in your export statement. You forgot to define the execute key. It should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'test',
  description: "Tester ting",
  execute: function(message, args) {
    message.channel.send("STOR TEST")
  }
}
```